# Applescript to click link on webpage

Tags: javascript, click, applescript

I'm trying to write an Applescript to automatically download account activity from a bank account. I've tried using the following:

```
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName(\"lnkDownloadTransactions.lightbox-launcher\").click();" in window 1
end tell
```

Where the HTML for the page is:

```
<span class="download ui-flyout-activator ui-flyout-opened">

<a class="lnkDownloadTransactions lightbox-launcher" href="#" data-minwidth="600" data-height="590" data-lightbox=".lightbox-downloadtransactionsWidget" data-accountglobalid="X" data-laststatementdate="06/25/2014">

<span class="icon iconInbox">/span>

<span class="text">Download Transactions/span>

</a>

<input type="hidden" class="urlCtrlaccountsdownloadtransactionspartialview" value="/NFCU/accounts/downloadtransactionspartialview">

<section class="lightbox lightbox-downloadtransactionsWidget" style="position: static; display: none; width: auto; min-height: 0px; height: 496px;" title="Download Transactions">    section class="account-downloadtransactionsLightboxContent">  /section>

<footer class="account-downloadtransactions-footer">

<div class="actionButtons submitFields">

<button type="button" class="cancelbutton cancel account-downloadtransactions-cancel-button" href="#">Cancel/button>

<button class="button account-downloadtransactions-download-button">Download</button>
        </div>
    </footer>/section>/span>
```

However it does not actually click on the link. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Class name is not unique on the page. It will return an array. Use ID. You can see an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24921155/3097556):

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    tell document 1
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('button-id').click();"
    end tell
end tell
```

You didn't post the entire button code, so don't see the ID.

Comment: Sorry, pretty new to this.  I think I added the rest of the HTML (at least that is all that shows up with the Safari's inspector).  If not, how do I find the button-id?

Comment: Well, the elements do not have ID defined, so you can't. Some browsers won't accept click() on links anyhow, just buttons.